# How to retrive perticular contacts only using Contacts API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-contacts-api, google-admin-sdk

I have added one custom attribute as "category". It's values should be 'Sales','Support' etc.
I have to retrieve only those contacts who have category as custom attributes.
 I tried using below code. But It is not giving the excepted results.

```
ContactFeed profileFeed = contactService.getFeed(new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"+domain+"/full/?xoauth_requestor_id="+adminEmail+"&start-index="+startIndex+"&q="+searchText),ContactFeed.class);
```

can anyone tell me ? Is there any way to retrieve only those contacts who have 'Category' as custom attribute.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, ive done ot before with some tricks. If you include a unique string in the properties, you can then search custom properties. For example prepend @ to all your custom properties, then search cor those properties that contain "@". Ive done this from apps script though not fhe raw http api.

Comment: where to add special character,for Custom Key or Custom value.?

Comment: In the value since it only searches values.

Comment: if you are using extended properties, you can query them with projections and use the q param to search for your special string (@ for example). Else, not sure how to do it with the http api. In Apps script you can use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getContactsByCustomField(Object,ExtendedField) and use the trick I told you, as in ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField('@', 'Category');